# Is it possible to upper bound conditional expectation expression: $\mathbb E[X | X > c] - c$?

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

As the titles suggests, I am trying to see if we can upper bound

$\mathbb{E}[X \text{ }| \text{ }X > c] - c$

For now, I am assuming bounded mean on both sides: $0 < m \leq \mathbb{E}[X] \leq M < \infty$, and bounded second moment: $\mathbb{E}[X^2] \leq V \leq \infty$. Additionally, X is a random variable with unbounded support. I have tried using simple bounds like Markov's and Chebyshev's but to no avail. If any further assumptions are needed, I'm also all ears. Any ideas? Thanks!

Edit: to be clear, I am hoping for a somewhat general bound, that is, we can assume nice things about the distribution of X (like being integrable, etc.), but I am looking for a bound for any such distribution, perhaps in terms of $c, F(x), f(x), m, M, V$, etc. I am not sure if I am just missing something from fundamental probability theory.

Comment: How about $P(X = x) = \frac{2}{x^3}$ for $x \geq 1$? Then we have $\Bbb E(X \mid X > c) = 2c$.

Comment: This may be true, but I was speaking more generally, that is, we can assume nice things about the distribution of X (like being integrable, etc.), but I am looking for a bound for any such distribution, perhaps in terms of c, F(x), f(x), etc.

Comment: Let $g(c)=E(X|X>c)-c=\frac {\int_c^{\infty}S(t)}{S(c)}$ where $S=1-F_X$. I think you can only state that $\limsup g(c)/c\le 1$ given finite variance.

Comment: Note that in general, if $X$ ($S$) has exponential tail,  $g(s)=\Theta(1)$, Gaussian - $g(s)=\Theta(\frac 1 s)$, power-law: $g(s)=\Theta(s)$ and constants don't depend on variance (since you can change $X$ to a mixture of $X$ and $0$ without changing $g$ while diminishing variance arbitrarily).

Comment: Thanks for this insight! I want to clarify: for your first comment, what do you mean by $S$? Because I see that $g(c) = \frac {\int_c^{\infty}tf(t) - cf(t) dt}{1 - F_X(c)}$; how do you get $xf(t) - cf(t) = 1 - F_X(t)$? 

For your second comment, by $X(S)$ do you mean $\bar{F}_X(c)$? 

I also want to believe lim sup $g(c)/c \leq 1$ but am unsure how to rigorously show this.

Comment: Also to clarify: let $h(c) = P(X > c)$, does your second comment imply that, if $h$ is power-law distributed, that $g(c)$ cannot be bounded (and constant with respect to $c$), even if variance is finite? Because if so, this sort of answers my question. How do you get $g(s)=\Theta(s)$? Thanks again.

Comment: 1. $S=1-F_X=\bar F_X$. 2. I don't get $xf(t)-cf(t) =1-F_X(t)$, but get equality of their integrals by using $E(X^+)=\int_0^\infty S(t)\,dt$. 3. $X (S)$ is not a function but just clarification of what I mean by the tail ($S$).4. Yes, if $S(c)\propto c^{-\alpha}$, then $g(s)=\frac s {\alpha-1}$ from the formula I wrote. Note that for finite variance you only need $\alpha>2$ which suggested the $\limsup \le 1$ (or something similar) but haven't shown this rigorously. If you only require finite mean, you need $\alpha>1$.

Comment: If you need $g(c)$ to be bounded, $X$ must be sub-exponential - in other words, its mgf should be defined outside of $0$ - but it's a much more severe restriction (that still allows for any kind of non-zero variance).

Comment: I see; could you explain how you arrived at this conclusion? I will look into this myself and try to work it out, but I really do appreciate your help and insight. I have been thinking about this problem for a while, and your direction of thought has been illuminating.